# Android and receiving sms

Tags: android, sms

I need to write some application on android. I want to application listen to incoming sms. When phone receives sms from specified phone number, application will recognize that the sms is from this phone number and do some work, process data from sms. Is there possible to do something like this in android? If there is some way to do that could you tell me how can I do it? Thanks for any help and tips.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of examples available for the same on web, here is one of them.

[Receive SMS](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/)

[Sample with Source](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/)

[Another One with Source](http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android)